# Attribute "lang" exists, but can not be used for this element.? W3C validation error

Tags: html, css, xhtml, w3c, xhtml-1.1

I'm using this dtd

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Error is for this attribute?

```
<html lang="en">
```

Should i remove this from DTD?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `<doctype html>`. You're not using XML anyway, and the xml:lang attribute doesn't do anything in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think [**this is it**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html):

> A. Changes from XHTML 1.0 Strict
>
> **1. On every element, the lang attribute has been removed in favor of the xml:lang attribute (as defined in [XHTMLMOD]).**

Comment: ok. it's may be the reason i will check. but why it's saying "Attribute “lang” exists" if it's not supported in this doctype. it only saying "but can not be used for this element.?"

Comment: Good point. I guess it's just a generic explanation of the error message, and they didn't take into account that the attribute was removed from the format altogether.